# Error in the response from php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using jquery and ajax to post the data from my html form (which has an input field for date, one select list and one multiselect list) in mysql using php. The problem is i am not able to post the data as it is giving error "There is error while submit". I don't know what is wrong with my code. There is no problem with the mysql connection. I am a neophyte in ajax and jquery hence can not be able to figure out the problem. Thanks in advance.

fire bug is showing this error in line "data:" 
"SyntaxError: missing : after property id"
Line: "chosen-supervisor-name: sup_data,"

jQuery:

```
function check_submit(){

var date_ass=$('#datepick').val();
    alert(date_ass);
var sup_data = $('#sel-sup-list').serialize();
    alert(sup_data);
var lab_data = $('#sel-lab-list').serialize();
    alert(lab_data);
    $.ajax({
        url: "insert.php",         
        type: "post",
        data: data: { date: date_ass, 
    chosen-supervisor-name: sup_data, 
    chosen-laborers-name: lab_data },
        success:function(data){
            $("#result").html(data);
        },
        error:function(){
            $("#result").html('There is error while submit');
        }
    }); 
};
```

php:

```
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['date']);
    $ccno_sup = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['chosen-supervisor-name']);
    $ccno_lab = $_POST['chosen-laborers-name'];

     foreach($ccno_lab as $i => $lab_ccno){

    $sql2="INSERT INTO Date_Supervisor_Laborers (date_of_association, ccNo_Supervisors, ccNo_Laborers)
    VALUES ('$date', '$ccno_sup', '$lab_ccno')";

        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql2)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }
        echo "The record is added";
        echo "<br/>";

    }
```

Comment: do you got the post data in the insert.php through ajax ?

Comment: @logan: I don't think so

Comment: Isn't `data:` supposted to be array `{param1: value1, param2: value2}` instead of concatenated querystring?

Comment: if the data is not received as POST in the insert.php, then the way you send the data to the file is wrong. So try like this "data: {status: status, name: name},"

Comment: @logan: okay let me try it..

Comment: i tried that and this is what i got: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token - idcards/project-kunal/try.php?date=2014%2F07%2F08

Comment: try passing the data in the same way you passed earlier like this data: $('#myForm').serialize() + "&moredata=" + morevalue, but assign it to a variable and alert it, see to that you have '&' symabol between date_ses, sup_data and lap_data

Comment: give it a try like this var formData =  $('#myForm').serialize() + "&moredata=" + morevalue;

$.ajax({
    url: args.url,
    data: formData,
    type: "POST",
    ...
})

Comment: @logan: look at the new error i am getting here it says "SyntaxError: missing : after property id"

Answer (score 0):

You are using post and in the same time you are trying to build a querystring for the `data` attribute.

As per the official documentation of jQuery's `ajax()`, the data via post should not be a concatenated querystring:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
```

So in your case, it should be

```
data: { date: date_ass, chosen-supervisor-name: sup_data, chosen-laborers-name: labdata }
```

And you might need to remove the `datatype` attribute.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token - idcards/project-kunal/try.php?date=2014%2F07%2F08

Comment: You are still using a querystring, post the code you are using now

Comment: $.ajax({
        url: "insert.php",         
        type: "post",
  data: { date: date_ass, chosen-supervisor-name: sup_data, chosen-laborers-name: lab_data },
        success:function(data){
            $("#result").html(data);
        },
        error:function(data){
            $("#result").html(data);
        }
    });

Comment: this is probably a different error, as it says `try.php`, instead of `insert.php`, so it's another part of your code

Comment: "SyntaxError: missing : after property id"
this is the new error i am getting

Comment: i dropped the idea of ajax, now i am using i-frame instead.
I tried to do that i guess there was a problem with the variable name. I changed the name and it was not giving any error but then there was no response from the php code so i decided to go on with the iframe

Answer (score 0):

Simply load your javascript with `https` instead of `http`

or use

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/l..
```

For example

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    or
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```